# Change colour of individual window in Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu-12.04, window-managers, ubuntu-unity

Is there a way to change the colour of an individual pre-existing window (border and/or title-bar) in Ubuntu 12.04 using the Unity desktop? For example, switching a specific `gedit` instance to have a green border. A quick Google didn't give me much, but I have heard it suggested that something could be done with accessibility framework.

I am open to the option of switching desktop environments if Ubuntu-Unity does not provide the means to accomplish my task and I am open to references to any API in any language, although Ruby would be preferable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CCSM (the Compiz manager) to set the colour of a window.  You can do it via hotkey - or your can set the filter if the window has a specific value (e.g. the title is gedit)
[image]

You can create different colour filters as you see fit.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that through the command line, please?

Comment: You can jump straight to the Colour Filter page by running `ccsm -p colorfilter` from the command line.

Comment: GUI's are really hard to automate. I was hoping to automate this process. Thus, the mention of the API in my question. Is there any way to accomplish this without the GUI?

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the config files that CCSM creates. Perhaps you could script their creation / deletion?